# How to measure the learning performance of neural network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Been wondering are there any ways to measure the learning performance of ANNs.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: does not look like you tried even to google this

Comment: Google `crossvalidation` and `hold-out set`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you talk about a neural network for classification.

Divide your training set in a real training set and a validation set using one of these methods:

- (k-fold / leave-one-out) [Cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)
- stratified holdout
- 0.632 bootstrap

Measure the performance of the ANN with one of these metrics:

- TP rate
- FP rate
- [F-measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score)
- accuracy
- [precision and recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)
- ...

For imbalanced classes, I recommend to read [this paper](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fncom.2014.00043/full).

For regression you need other metrics, e.g.

- mean squared error
- mean absolute error
- [R2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)